# LoadLibrary fails with lasterror 0x43 The network name cannot be found

Tags: winapi

My program dynamically loads a number of DLL's using LoadLibrary and (on literally all machines) these load successfully, on one machine some of these DLL's do not get loaded.  I added code to trace lasterror and this reports "0x43 The network name cannot be found.".

The machine in question is running Windows 7 Enterprise x64, the DLL is a 32 bit DLL, this shouldn't be an issue and (in fact) this is my development environment.

I also tried converting the name of the DLL (which includes the path) to a short filename and used that in the call to LoadLibrary, I still got the same error.

Any ideas?

//*eggbox

Comment: LoadLibrary has a [complicated search path algorithm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682586%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), could an invalid network path have ended up on the search path?

Comment: The filename provided to LoadLibrary is fully qualified, e.g. C:\Program Files (x86)\MyApp\DLLs\AssetModule.dll, or the short name version.

Comment: Sure, but what about libraries which it depends upon?

Comment: Good point, the answer below gives me a clue as to what I can use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download [Procmon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) let it run and filter for you dll name. This will immediately give you the locations where the dll was searched and which access path did return 0x43.

You get even the call stacks if you have the pdbs for your code as well (C/C++ only no managed code).

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'll have try it with my system and see whether I can see a difference with the users system.

Comment: Procmon did give me some information which points to failure to load a dependent DLL.  The strange thing is that the dependent DLL was loaded immediately prior to the one that failed to load. At least I have something to go on now, thanks for the help.

Comment: Just to let everyone know that I found out what was going on.  The customer had an entry in their path statement that pointed to a network share, something like **\\machine\folder\subfolder**, it looks like this was inaccessible (hence the error code).  The **fix** was to remove the entry from their path, simple really but frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

Run the program through [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) in its Profile mode and let that fine tool tell you exactly what is going wrong.

Comment: I tried Dependency Walker in Profile mode but for both x86 and x64 machines it never got to the end of loading (on my system).  Nice idea though.

Comment: David, I tried this on my dev machine where normally it loads successfully and it never got to the end.